# Understanding mixed non-blocking and blocking assignments in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I am reading *Nonblocking Assignments in Verilog Synthesis, Coding Styles That Kill!*
by *Clifford E. Cummings*.

On page 16 it says that you can

```
module nbex2 (q, a, b, clk, rst_n);
   output q;
   input clk, rst_n;
   input a, b;
   reg q;

   always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n)
      if (!rst_n) q <= 1'b0;
      else q <= a ^ b;
endmodule
```

split the `always` block into a pure combinational and pure sequential part:

```
module nbex2 (q, a, b, clk, rst_n);
   output q;
   input clk, rst_n;
   input a, b;
   reg q;

   always @(a or b)
      y = a ^ b;

   always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n)
      if (!rst_n) q <= 1'b0;
      else q <= y;

endmodule
```

My understanding though in the splitted version is, that the order of execution of both always blocks is not defined.

1. If `b` changes at a positive clock edge and the bottom always block executes first, then the right-hand side of `q <= y` is evaluated yielding the value that is saved in register `y`. The value is not yet assigned to `q` as this is a non-blocking assignment.
2. Then the top `always` block is executed updating the `y` register with `a ^ b`. The `y` value is directly updated as this is a blocking assignment.
3. At the end of the cycle `q` is assigned the value evaluated in step 1, which is the *old* `y` value.

The document says though, that both versions have the same outcome. where is the flaw in my thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1. If b changes at a positive clock edge and the bottom always block executes first, then the right-hand side of q <= y is evaluated yielding the value that is saved in register y. The value is not yet assigned to q as this is a non-blocking assignment.*

First of all blocking/non-blocking assignments are simulation-only artifact and are in the language to mimic hardware behavior during simulation (if used correctly).
Verilog is an event-driven simulator, which means that it runs simulation till there is any activity in the code (signal values change). There are several sequential event-driven buckets. For this explanation two of them are important: the bucket when blocking assignments are evaluated and a subsequent bucket where non-blocking assignments are evaluated.

So, `y = a^b` is evaluated in the first one. `q <= y` is evaluated in the second one. This provides you with an order of evaluation. Simulation buckets are defined in verilog standard, you can read more about them there. Just for more contents, if `q` is used in a blocking assignment in code, the whole sequence of blocks will repeat in simulation again, till the code get quiescent (no more signals change).

*2.Then the top always block is executed updating the y register with a ^ b. The y value is directly updated as this is a blocking assignment.*

It does not matter if the block is the firs or the last. The blocking assignment will be executed before non-blocking, no matter what.

*3. At the end of the cycle q is assigned the value evaluated in step 1, which is the old y value.*

The **new** value of 'y' will be assigned to 'q' in the second bucket. The confusion caused by using wrong examples, like `q <= y; z = q;` in a single *always* block. Since `z =`  is executed in the first bucket, it just does not see updated value of `q` yet and the old value of 'q' will be assigned to it. Don't ever mix blocking and non-blocking in a single always block.

Answer (score 0):

The order of execution of the two always blocks is not defined **if** they are sensitive events scheduled in the same region. If there is a defined order relationship between the clock edge and the signals `a` and `b`, then there will be a defined order execution relationship. You have to look back to see when signals `a` and `b` get updated. Assuming all sequential logic gets updated with non-blocking assignments, then `a` and `b` get updated in a different region than the clock.

Answer (score 0):

The operation of DFFs has 2 phases: evaluation and update. In evaluation phase, ALL combinational logic in the design are evaluated to prepare the values on D pins of all DFFs. Then in update phase, ALL DFF D pin values are copied to their Q pins. DFF Q pins may be the inputs of combinational logic. Then goes to evaluation phase of the next clock cycle, and so on.

In your case, suppose a and b are also from DFFs:

```
Cycle 0, udpate: a and b are udpated
Cycle 1, evaluation: y = a ^ b
Cycle 1, update: q <= y. Where y is the newest value.
```

This should be no problem.